# It correct to check the parameters in the initialize list?

Tags: c++

It's correct to check the parameters in the initialize list and if it's necessary lauch an exception ?

```
Fraction::Fraction(Sign sign, unsigned numerator , unsigned denominator) :numerator_(numerator),denominator_( (denominator==0)? throw std::invalid_argument {"denominator cannont be 0"} : denominator ), sign_(  ((numerator!=0 && sign ==Sign::ZERO)||(numerator==0 && sign !=Sign::ZERO)) ? throw std::invalid_argument {"numerato not zero and sign zero "} :sign )

{
    unsigned div = gcd(this->numerator_, this->denominator_);
    if(div!=0)
    {
        this->setDenRaw(denominator/div);
        this->setNumRaw(numerator/div);
    }
    else
    {
        this->setDenRaw(denominator);
        this->setNumRaw(numerator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget you can use a function rather than having it all inline. This would make it much easier for me to read personally. Something like `: denominator_(enforceValidDenominator(denominator))` makes it pretty clear to me that something such as an exception could very well happen in there without cluttering up the initializer list and still allowing for initialization rather than assignment.

Comment: This is better to check in the constructor or call a method Inside the constructor to check the parameters ?

Comment: You could validate the parameters in the constructor body, even after you assigned them to members in member init list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the "assert" statement in the constructor body to throw an error if someone supplies unwanted input. [Here's an example fraction class which errors with a 0 denominator](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/9-14-overloading-the-assignment-operator/).

Also, you don't need to write `this->` before referencing a local variable in this context.

Comment: Disagree with this advice, `assert` is ignored in a release build so it is not effective in guarding against user input errors. And  in a debug build it will bomb out of the program in an ugly way. Throwing an exception is clearly better than asserting  (although there are other options too)

Comment: It is only ignored in release builds if you `#define NDEBUG`, or you're using certain IDEs like visual studio, in which case you can remove it from the project-level preprocessor directives. I can't argue whether `assert` or throwing an exception is better in this case as I don't know the context of the code.